# Model Binding dynamic Property Names

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a JSON data source I'm trying to model bind. The problem is the property names are the object's id. For example:

```
{
    "1": someObject,
    "2": someObject,
    "3": someObject
}
```

My code I'm using to retrieve and parse this is:

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(UnitURL);
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponseAsync().Result;
string json;

using(var s = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
{
    json = s.ReadToEndAsync().Result;
}

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<rootObject>(json);
```

I'd like rootObject to look something like:

```
public class rootObject
{
    public Dictionary<int, someObject> Things { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Then either the Json would need to be updated to match the desired object graph, like...

```
{
    "Things": {
        "1": someObject,
        "2": someObject,
        "3": someObject
    }
}
```

Or deserialize the original JSON to `Dictionary<int, someObject>` and then assign it to a `rootObject`, like...

```
var things = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, someObject>>(json);
var root = new rootObject {
    Things = things
};
```